# Jquery plugin insertion in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I wanted to insert responsive nav jquery plugin into the directive. This plugin provides keyboard accessible navigation. I have tried the below example of jquery plugin initiation but prompts an error like responsiveNav is not a function.

What is the wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div responsive-nav>
        <ul class="page-sidebar-menu page-sidebar-menu-closed nav-menu">
            <!-- DOC: To remove the search box from the sidebar you just need to completely remove the below "sidebar-search-wrapper" LI element -->

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/" ui-sref="dashboard" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkHome" class="active" ng-click="vm.menuActive()">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                    <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"  ng-show="vm.inClientOrganization">
                <a href="javascript:;" ui-sref="policysearch" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkPolicy" ng-click="vm.menuActive()">
                    <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
                    <span class="title">Policy Search</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" ng-show="vm.inClientOrganization">
                <a href="#/todo" ui-sref="tasksearch" ui-sref-active="active" id="dbdLnkTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="sub-nav" aria-controls="sub-nav">
                    <i class="icon-check"></i>
                    <span class="title">Task Search</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" aria-labelledby="dbdLnkTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" id="sub-nav">
                    <li ng-repeat="task in vm.availableTasks">
                        <a id="dbdLnkAvailable{{$index}}" href="javascript:;" ng-click="vm.handleTask(task)" ng-class="{'cn-active' : vm.activeMenuItem}">
                            <i ng-class="task.icon"></i> <span class="title">{{task.description}}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {
        customToggle: "#nav-toggle", // Selector: Specify the ID of a custom toggle
        enableFocus: true,
        enableDropdown: true,
        openDropdown: '<span class="screen-reader-text">Open sub menu</span>',
        closeDropdown: '<span class="screen-reader-text">Close sub menu</span>',
            open: function () {

            },
            close: function () {

            },
            resizeMobile: function () {

            },
            resizeDesktop: function () {

            },
        });
```

Created directive in angular.

**Angular**

```
angular
        .module('app.core')
        .directive('responsiveNav', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.responsiveNav({
                            enableFocus: true,
                            enableDropdown: true,
                            openDropdown: '<span class="screen-reader-text">Open sub menu</span>',
                            closeDropdown: '<span class="screen-reader-text">Close sub menu</span>',
                            open: function () { },
                            close: function () { },
                            resizeMobile: function () { },
                            resizeDesktop: function () { }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Comment: Do you know how to create an Angular directive? you're not providing enough information. What plugin is this? we need more info.

When initializing an Angular directive, you get access to the element, some plugins will let you pass the element, some others won't. The way you're doing it is anti-angular and will not be reusable. Try looking at this article and comment with more info https://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html

Comment: Update more info..

Comment: element.responsiveNav is not a function, because element is a jquery lite element, if you want to use the jquery you have to do something like $(element).responsiveNav or responsiveNav(element.class). Also, are you including the directive in the template? maybe include the ul and nav in the template property of the directive.

Comment: though using $(element).responsiveNav jquery gives same error. responsiveNav(element.class) also tells can not find responsvieNav. Yes, included in template.